# Changing only the calculation in a function

Tags: python, function, call

Is it possible to have a function where you specify a function within it as a variable.

For example, I have two functions which follow exactly the same process, except one calculaate the **Average** using `np.mean` and the other calculates the **standard deviation** where only `np.std` is different.

i.e.
it would be defined:
`def calculate(function)`

you would call one in the script like:

`calculate(mean)`
 and the other 
`calculate(std)`

I'm just wondering if it is possible to do something like this s it would greatly reduce my script length.

**EDIT**

Sorry I should have said that I wanted the mean and std to be the ones predefined in numpy. `getattr()` in Xu's answer worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getattr` to get the method object according to the method name:

```
def calculate(function):
    func = getattr(np, function)
    func(...)   # do what you want

calculate("mean") # calculate the average number 
calculate("std")  # calculate the standard deviation
```

Comment: Thanks @Xu Ding, I should have specified it was a method object

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.

Example:

```
def addIt(x):
    return x+x

def test(fn):
    for x in xrange(5):
        print fn(x)


test(addIt)
```

Output:

```
0
2
4
6
8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f1(t): return t * 2 
def f2(t): return t * t 

def comb(t,f): return f(t)

print comb(10, f1) 
print comb(10, f2)
```